# getJSON problem (jquery)

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to use getJSON to submit username and password to a webservice and alert  "hi"

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON(address+"?format=json&jsoncallback=?", {CustomerEmail: email, Password: password},
  function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

The http headers submit a 200 message so it should be OK but it does not enter the function, does anyone know why please?

Comment: Are the pages located on the same server? Most likely your are violating the same-origin policy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Felix Kling: As soon as `jsoncallback=` is within the query string, its treated as `jsonp`, isnt it?

Comment: But it gives me a 200 message meaning OK, access not denied.

Comment: @jAndy: The documentation says it should be `callback=?`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ see the cat example

Comment: You will still receive 200 as status code, even if you do violate the policy.

Comment: "Additional Notes:

    * Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
    * Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Examples:
Example: Loads the four most recent cat pictures from the Flickr JSONP API. "

..............

so it should not have the same origin policy

Comment: Yes, if you use jsonp correctly which you do not (I updated my answer).

Comment: I copy pasted the one they are using in the site and basically just changed the url and the parameters

Answer (score 4):

Are the pages located on the same server? Most likely your are violating the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You could make use of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) but [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) expects the parameter to be named `callback` instead of `jsoncallback`:

> *JSONP*
>
> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" in the URL, the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

So to make it work in your case, you could try with `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: address+"?format=json",
  data: {CustomerEmail: email, Password: password},
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "jsoncallback",
  success: function(data) {
    alert("hi");
  }
});
```

Comment: then how would I submit the data to the webservice please?

Comment: @C.: Oh sorry, I forget to add this, I updated my answer (but actually it is described in the documentation ;))

Answer (score 1):

Check, if your received JSON data is valid. Especially, that all strings (even in property names) are properly "quoted".

From the jQuery documentation:

> **Important**: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error,
>   the request will usually fail
>   silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing
>   of JSON data for this reason. JSON is
>   a data-interchange format with syntax
>   rules that are stricter than those of
>   JavaScript's object literal notation.
>   For example, all strings represented
>   in JSON, whether they are properties
>   or values, must be enclosed in
>   double-quotes. For details on the JSON
>   format, see http://json.org/.